# How to read DATA type from a sas7bdat file through pyreadstat?meta.original_variable_types giving different values?

Tags: python-3.x, sas

```
import pyreadstat
df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat('c:/ae.sas7bdat')
print(meta.original_variable_types)
```

This code prints the values as following

```
{
    "TRIAL_NAME":"$",
    "SITEMNEMONIC":"$",
    "PATIENTNUMBER":"$",
    "VISITID":"BEST",
    "VISITREFNAME":"$",
    "SEQ":"BEST",
    "PANELNAME":"$",
    "STATUS":"DND",
    "COMPDT":"$",
    "COMPTM":"$",
    "SPECID":"$"
}
```

From SAS documentation I understood that `$` represents character and `BEST` represents Numeric. But what are other types then? When I opened my file in SAS viewer I can see type as character and Numeric. How can I retrieve that? Attaching the image of meta information from SAS viewer. I want to retrieve that `type`

[image: meta information]

Comment: Your images are too small to be legible and SAS only has two data types, numeric/character. Formats control the appearance of the variables, such as currency, or comma formats or dates and datetimes.

Comment: Can you just zoom the picture?you can see.I want to retreive that "TYPE" mentioned in picture.Is there any API in python pyreadstat to retreive those types?original_value_types returns the original format type only.

Comment: No, your pictures don't zoom and are unreadable.

Comment: @Reeza For your future reference - right click, then open image in a new tab - it will open at full resolution.  StackOverflow automatically limits the resolution to the right width for the question (via imgur's multiple sizing).

Comment: Your python results seems to just be returning the name of the format that is permanently attached to the variable in the dataset.  But in your example picture from SAS Universal viewer it does not show any variables that do not have a permanent format specifications attached, but some do not have any permanent informat attached.  Do you know what result your python statements would produce for variables that do not have a format permanently attached in the dataset?

Comment: Yes tom,i tried with some other files that do not have format and informat.in that case its returning null.So i am unable to find out the datatype that time.the work around that i have done is checking the datatype of dataframe and analysing from it.I dont have any clue how to retreive the datatype in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need type, then it is easy: in pyreadstat if $ then it is charachter, if not, it is numeric.

What you are seeing in pyreadstat is what you have in the format column of SAS without the variable width (which is stored separately in pyreadstat in meta.variable_display_width). You will observe in your screenshot that all character variables have a format that starts with $ , the number that comes next is the variable width.

SAS has only two types: charachter and number, therefore if not a character it is a number. The format tells SAS how to display the variable. For characters it is just display the charachter ($) with cerain width, as there are no more alternatives. Numbers can be displayed in different ways, things like BEST, but also as DATE if they represent the number of days since Jan 1st 1960, as DATETIME if they represent the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1960, etc.

In case formats are missing, you can check if the data in a column is a string, in which case the type in SAS was character. Anything else was numeric:

```
import pyreadstat

df, meta = pyreadstat.read_xport('file.xpt')
dtypes = zip(list(df.columns), list(df.dtypes))

sas_types = dict()
for colname, coltype in dtypes:
    if coltype == object:
        nonan = df[colname].dropna()
        if not nonan.empty:
            if type(nonan[0]) == str:
                sas_types[colname] = 'character'
            else:
                sas_types[colname] = 'numeric'
        else:
            sas_types[colname] = '?'
    else:
        sas_types[colname] = 'numeric'
```

EDIT:

In pyreadstat version 1.1.0 you have now meta.readstat_variable_types. This is a dictionary with variable name as key, while the value is the binary type Readstat extracted from the file. In the case of SAS and SPSS you may get either 'string' (character) or 'double' (numeric). In Stata you may also get 'int8', 'int32' and float.

Comment: Hi Otto,I was waiting for your reply.i applied this logic and retreived the datatype on the basis of $ after going SAS programming documentation.but the problem is in some of my data format and informat are missing.In that case applying this logic is difficult.but data type is always there.The workaround that i have done right now is i retreived values of the files in a dataframe and checked the datatype of dataframe incase formats are missing.it would be great if you can suggest any other direct method to retreive datatype in case of formats are missing?

Comment: df, meta = pyreadstat.read_xport('c:/dm.xpt')
list_types=list(df.dtypes)
new_list=[]
for i in range(len(list_types)):
    single_type=list_types[i]
    if(single_type == object):
        new_list.append('Character')
    else:
        new_list.append('Numeric')                                                                                                The above code i have written for retreiving the datatype from an xpt file where format and informat are missing

Comment: That will do most of times. To be completely correct, for the columns of type object you need to check the first non NaN element. If it is of type str, then you are sure it was character in SAS. This check is needed because a date or datetime may be if type object but not a string, while they are of type numeric in SAS.

Comment: Thanks Otto,this looks perfect.I have done with my files.i can retreive it.one more dout i have is how can i retreive the informat from SAS7bdat/xpt files.

Comment: Unfortunately original_variable_types is the only piece of information regarding formats we can get, and I think that is the SAS format. Informats we cannot get. But informats are how the original text data was read when imported into SAS, once that text data is not available anymore I don't see its relevance.

Comment: Regarding SAS variable type, I am going to add a new variable in the future to hold wether the data was character or numeric, so that you and others don't have to guess it. I will make it available on the next version. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much otto.That will be very helpful.when can i expect the next version.I am a clinical data engineer.we want that in our next release in may.pyreadstat is very fast and we are addicted to that.

Comment: I would say in a couple of weeks. I'll add an edit to my answer once it is in production.